# Enumeration in powers of 2

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I would like to enumerate a list, but instead of the standard numbering

```
 1. bar
 2. bar
 3. bar
 4. bar
 5. bar
```

I would like the labels to be powers of 2 (automatically generated):

```
 1. bar
 2. bar
 4. bar
 8. bar
16. bar
```

etc. Can this be done with `enumitem` or `pgf`?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need this?

Comment: somes questions requiere as answer the sum of the correct options, witch are given in powers of two

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Examples with `xfp` or `pgfmath` are shown below. Note that the `enumi` counter is for the outermost level, if this is a nested list you need `enumii`/`enumiii`/`enumiv`, depending on the level of nesting.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\protect\fpeval{2^(\value{enumi}-1)}.}]
\item
foo
\item
bar
\item
baz
\item
foo
\item
bar
\item
baz
\item
foo
\item
bar
\item
baz
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\protect\pgfmathparse{int(2^(\value{enumi}-1))}\protect\pgfmathresult.}]
\item
foo
\item
bar
\item
baz
\item
foo
\item
bar
\item
baz
\item
foo
\item
bar
\item
baz
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It returned the error "Font \TU/lmr/m/n/12=[lmroman12-regular]:+tlig; at 12pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \normalsize". Is there a way to do these calculations with pgf?

Comment: @geekformoney Yes (see updated answer), I don't know why this would trigger a font error though.

Answer (score 12):

No other package used, only `enumitem`'s way of adding enumerate counter and evaluating with `\numexpr`, defining a new list in order to keep the regular `enumerate` list clean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{powercntr}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\poweroftwocalc}[1]{%
  \ifnum1<\value{#1}%
  \setcounter{powercntr}{\numexpr\c@powercntr*2}
  \fi
}
\def\poweroftwo#1{\poweroftwocalc{#1}\expandafter\@poweroftwo\csname the#1\endcsname}
\def\@poweroftwo#1{\thepowercntr}

\AddEnumerateCounter{\poweroftwo}{\@poweroftwo}{4096}

\newlist{powerlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[powerlist,1]{before=\setcounter{powercntr}{1}}

\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{powerlist}[label={\poweroftwo*}]
\item And
\item Now
\item For
\item Something
\item Completely 
\item Different
\item Was
\item Said
\item Very
\item Frequently
\item In
\item Monty
\item Python's
\item Flying
\item Circus
\end{powerlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

No other packages used, no e-TeX needed. Basically a rip-off of @ChristianHupfer's idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{powercntr}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\updatepowercntr}[1]%
  {\arabic{powercntr}\addtocounter{powercntr}{\value{powercntr}}}

\newlist{powerlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[powerlist,1]{before=\setcounter{powercntr}{1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{powerlist}[label={\updatepowercntr*}]
\item And
\item Now
\item For
\item Something
\item Completely 
\item Different
\item Was
\item Said
\item Very
\item Frequently
\item In
\item Monty
\item Python's
\item Flying
\item Circus
\end{powerlist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here is a version demonstrating `\AddEnumerateCounter` and using `xintcore` for the arithmetic.  This way you can start at any (positive) power of 2 you choose and nesting is no problem.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xintcore}

\AddEnumerateCounter*{\poweroftwo}{\internalpoweroftwoname}{1}
\newcommand{\poweroftwo}[1]{\xintiiPow{2}{\value{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\poweroftwo*},start={19}]
\item A
\item list
\item enumerated
\item with
\item powers
\item of
\item two
\item starting
\item at
\item the
\item initial
\item value
\item 5
\item 2
\item 4
\item 2
\item 8
\item 8
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

You probably want to use this with `leftmargin=*,widest*=38`.

I originally used the `bigintcalc` package but @jfbu kindly pointed out that `xintcore` is significantly faster.  For `bigintcalc` the syntax

```
\newcommand{\poweroftwo}[1]{\bigintcalcPow{2}{\number\value{#1}}}
```

with `\number` is needed.

Note I have simplified the syntax from the `enumitem` manual.  We no longer need a helper macro, and can avoid `@` in names, so do not have to encase in `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.  The second argument of `\AddEnumerateCounter` looks like a macro, but is actually stripped of the leading `\` to produce a character string to build internal names in `enumitem`.

Comment: +1 syntax with package xintcore would be `\newcommand{\@poweroftwo}[1]{\xintiiPow 2 {#1}}`

Comment: @jfbu I have now simplified this further, so your example (after `\usepackage{xintcore}`) would now be `\newcommand{\poweroftwo}[1]{\xintiiPow 2 {\number\value{#1}}}`

Comment: +2 `;-)` I am obedient LaTeX citizen hence the official recommended way is `\xintiiPow{2}{\number\value{#1}}` `:)`

Comment: @jfbu Good syntax point - I'll update my corresponding use to add brackets around the `2` etc.

Comment: @jfbu Impressive speed up - I have now changed my answer to use `xintcore`

Comment: I am a bit embarrassed by the formulation... (as I am the author of xintcore...) perhaps I could suggest something like "this answer uses xintcore, it could also use bigintcalc package as in my original version."

Comment: @jfbu I don't think you should be embarassed - if you hadn't pointed it out I wouldn't have known and it is definite improvement.  Thank you for your work on `xint`

Comment: I now looked at `xint`'s doc, and it reminded me that `\xintiiPow{2}{\value{#1}}` syntax works. Indeed the exponent for powers, or the argument to factorial are automatically inserted inside `\numexpr..\relax` context by `xintcore`, contrarily to general "big integers" argument which would create arithmetic overflow. The ``xintfrac`` package has macros ``\xintPow/\xintFloatPow/\xintFloatPower``, and the latter is the variant allowing big integers also in exponent (doc gives example ``\xintFloatPower{1.1547}{34359738368}`` where exponent exceeds ``2^31`` TeX bound).